# Change the OK Cancel string in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I was wondering is it possible to change the OK Cancel Button to custom string in java?
I have

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(message, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Right now, the button will show "OK" and "Cancel". Is it possible to change the text for that?
for example into "A" and "B" or maybe japanese text?

Thank you

Comment: So what you want is to show "Ok", "Cancel" in Japanese?

Comment: It doesn't have to be japanese.. but yes...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like instead of `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` you are going to have to use [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29), which lets you supply your own texts as an array.

Try the following:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
        "Do you like this answer?", 
        "Feedback", 
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
        null, 
        new String[]{"Yes I do", "No I don't"}, // this is the array
        "default");
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) in the detailed class description part: 
    `You aren't limited to this set of option buttons. You can provide any buttons you want using the options parameter.` 
 What (options) is also described there. Anyway the default texts (i.e. OK/Cancel) are usually based on the computer locale, but for custom labels use the method described in the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question. But for future reference, we can do it by add 2 lines before `showConfirmDialog`:

```java
UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Go back");
UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "Save");
```