# Can I localize the JOptionPane OK/Cancel option?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have a question regarding the JOptionPane.showInputDialog. The buttons I have are OK and  Cancel, but I was wondering if it was possible to localize these to a particular Locale i will provide?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763075/change-the-ok-cancel-string-in-joptionpane

Comment: Yeah, @Areca, that could definitely be a way out of it. I’d still wish for a cleaner solution to localization exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation? Or try your favourite search engine? This is quite easy when you know how:

```
    JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guten Tag");
```

The above shows an input dialog with buttons labeled “OK” and “Abbrechen” (which I believe to be German usage, I am not an expert there, and in any case it is different from the “Cancel” label I get otherwise).